# Функция генерирующая HTML в TWIG

Tags: twig

`Twig` используется вне `symfony`. Стоит задача сделать аналог функции `form()` имеющейся в `symfony`. т.е. в шаблоне пишем `{{form(form)}}` данная функция сгенерит HTML и вставит его в шаблон. 
Вопрос как сделать чтоб это работало? сейчас если я вывожу `HTML` он уже отформатирован в спец символы и воспринимается как текст.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вдруг кому будет нужно.
Создаем класс

```
class Project_Twig_Extension extends \Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension 
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig\TwigFunction('test', [$this, 'getTest'], ['is_safe'=>['html']]),
        ];
    }

    public function getTest() {
        return '<div>test</div>';
    }

}


$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);
$twig->addExtension(new Project_Twig_Extension());
```

И всё прекрасно работает.
Ключевым моментом было вывести `html`, за это отвечает параметр `['is_safe'=>['html']]`

вот очень крутая статья https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/advanced.html#creating-an-extension. Всё подробно описано.